# Javascript: Not 'finding' the prototype function of an object when called from another function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

IN THIS CODE BELOW GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR
Uncaught type error: ball.draw is not a function!!
But ball has been defined as a new Ball and Ball has a prototype function, draw.
when not in the init() function the  ball gets drawn fine??
Any ideas graciously received.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
var ball2;
var ball;
window.onload = init(context);

ball2 = new Ball(50, '#100fff');
ball2.x = 150;
ball2.y = 150;
ball2.draw(context);


function init(){
   ball = new Ball(50, '#0000ff');
   ball.x = 100;
   ball.y = 100;
   ball.draw(context);
}

//ball object

function Ball (radius, color){
    this.radius = radius;
    this .color = color;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function(context){
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
};
```

Comment: `window.onload = init.bind(null, context);` This should fix it. And it looks like you have a confusing order with your code. Setup the classes before using it.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: I did initially have the constructor at the top. The only way I've got this to work so far is to have the Ball constructor and prototype in a separate js file that sits first in the HTML code.